# Time-dependent Schrodinger equation from variational principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, path-integral, variational-principle, density-functional-theory

In the paper,  ["Density-functional theory for time-dependent systems" Physical Review Letters 52 (12): 997](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.52.997) the authors mentioned that the action
$$ A= \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \mathrm dt \langle \Phi(t) | i \hbar\;\partial / \partial t - \hat{H}(t) | \Phi(t)  \rangle \tag{1} $$

provides the solution of time-dependent Schrödinger equation at its stationary point.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-dependent_density_functional_theory)  called (1) as the Dirac action without further reference.

If I do a variation, indeed the stationary point of action (1) gives
$$  i \hbar\;\partial / \partial t | \Phi(t)  \rangle = \hat{H}(t) | \Phi(t)  \rangle $$

However, from path-integral point of view, the least action principle is only a limiting case when $\hbar \rightarrow 0$. In general, there is no least action principle in quantum mechanics.

My question is, how to reconcile these two aspects? What does vary of action (1) mean?

Comment: This is simply another variational principle, not necessarily connected with the classical action. From the Ritz variational functional $E[\psi] = \int d^3x \psi^*(x) H \psi(x)$ you will get the time indepent Schrödigner equation, this is just a natural extension of this.

Comment: What, exactly, is the question here? You vary $(1)$, you obtain the Schrödinger equation. What is the *question* about that?

Comment: Action is just a term used for certain kind of functionals. The qm action and classical action are different things, in different spaces. Thus, there is nothing to resolve. (Assuming that I understood the question right)

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in an path integral with the action:
$$
\mathcal{S}= \int_{t_0}^{t_1} dt \langle \Phi(t) | i \hbar\partial / \partial t - \hat{H}(t) | \Phi(t)  \rangle \tag{1}
$$
then $\Phi(k, t)=\langle k| \Phi(t)  \rangle$ is now an operator or a mude variable inside the path integral. The bridge between the operator and path integral linguage is:

$$
\langle \alpha|\mathcal{T}\left(...\hat{\Phi}(k,t)...\right)|\beta\rangle=\int \mathcal{D}\phi(k,t)\mathcal{D}\bar{\phi}(k,t)\left(...\phi(k,t)...\right)e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}\mathcal{S}}
$$

And the Action is now written as:
$$
\mathcal{S}= \int_{t_0}^{t_1} dt \int dk\, \bar{\phi}(k,t) ( i \hbar\partial / \partial t - \hat{H}_k(t) ) \phi(k, t)  
$$
with $\hat{H}_k(t)$ being an linear operator acting on functions $\phi(k,t)$.

This is the [second quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_quantization). Now we have an complex quantum field theory. Taking the canonical momentum of the fields and using the Dirac rule of quantization:
$$
\left[\hat{\Phi}(k,t),\hat{\Phi}^{\dagger}(k',t')\right]_\pm=\delta(k'-k)\delta(t'-t)
$$
This is the algebra of [annihilation and creation operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creation_and_annihilation_operators). Because the theory are linear ($\mathcal{L}$ bilinear in $\Phi$) the number operator 
$$
N=\sum_{k}\Phi(k, t)^{\dagger}\Phi(k, t)
$$
commutes with $\mathcal{H}$, the hamiltonian related to the action $\mathcal{S}$. This imply that $N$ is a constant of motion. The schrodinger equation (equation of motion) is obeyed by a field operator:
$$
i \hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \hat{\Phi}(k,t)= \hat{H}_k(t)\hat{\Phi}(k,t)
$$
and if you find eigenfunctions of $u_n(k,t)$ for the $\hat{H}_k(t)$ we have:

$$
\hat{\Phi}(k,t)=\sum_{n}u_n(k,t)\hat{c}_n
$$

where $\hat{c}_n$ is the [annihilation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creation_and_annihilation_operators) of a particle. You see that your prediction would be the same.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: The question are concerned with the histories that do not obey the classical equation of motion of the action. Here I show that this histories only give us an discription where the number of particles can be dynamicals. But, because we have a symmetry (bilinear terms only), we have a symmetry that is the conservation of number of particles. So, pratically we have the same thing but with different discriptions.

Answer (score 1):

There definitely is a  least action principle in quantum mechanics, indeed, the path-integral method is based on it. Feynman's doctoral thesis is titled:" the least action principle in quantum mechanics". Please see, e.g., http://cds.cern.ch/record/101498/files/?ln=en

Comment: Link-only answers generally are frowned upon, as links can - as I'd put it - "die". Can you explain this more?